# IP address changes on Apache server

Tags: internet, ubuntu-11.04, apache-http-server

So I recently set up an apache server on Ubuntu 11.04 in my apartment. I plug directly into the wall and I know that this goes to a router because I can connect to it via 192.168.1.1. I set up port forwarding and everything was running smoothly until the next day. The server was down and when I did an ifconfig I found that the ip had changed to 66.XX.XXX.XXX wheres the day before it was 69.XX.XXX.XXX. I am not able to connect to the router. When I unplug and re plug it into the wall port I get a 192 number for a day then it changes again. Is there anything that would of caused the ip to change and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, this is hard to say for sure due to the ips in the example.

`66.x.x.x` and `69.x.x.x` would be in completely different ranges and even if your ISP has a few different IP blocks, something seems not right here as you should have not been able to connect to your router on `192.168.1.1` so I am a little confused as to what is going on.

My guess is one of the following:

1. You are connected to a different router.
2. The router has bridged mode on some ports.
3. You have multiple routers.
4. (sort of combined with 3) - the wiring at your apartment is not straight forward and it is ending up in the wrong port.

All this being said, unless you are using static IP addresses, if a machine is not on when the DHCP lease expires, it is possible to loose your reservation and that IP address.

I hope this helps a little, but, again, it sounds a little weird from what you have said and to help you further, I really need to know more about your network topology.